# How do I hide the WorkFlow tab on a NetSuite custom record?

Tags: netsuite

I developed a custom record on NetSuite, and by default a workflow tab is shown to the user on this edit / view modes. Is there a way to hide it, using NetSuite's API or SuiteBuilder?

As an alternative, just placing it as the last tab would work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of any API or SuiteBuilder. You can easily achieve this by form customization.
Go to your Custom Record Type and below you will find forms subtab. click on

```
forms subtab -->  Edit or Customize
```

[image]

On the first subtab just uncheck the tab which you doesn't want to see in your record.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rockstar, this worked for me! I completely forgot these options since I'm working basically with the view mode, where the link to customize the form isn't shown.

Do you know a way to make this custom form the only one available? Since this is a custom record, I have no use for the original form. Thanks!

Comment: @LuizFernandoMeier you can find the `preferred` radio button in the `Forms` subtab of the custom record type. So you can select the form which you want to attach to your custom record and want to see in your edit/view mode.

Comment: In fact, I was using this preferred option already. I was just wondering if is possible to hide the original form at all, so the user cannot select it. But I think this isn't possible to achieve. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In both view nad edit modes by customizing form you can hide the workflow tab

Comment: Thank you @Karthik. As I'm editing mainly the view mode, I didn't notice the link to customize the form on edit mode. Do you know a way to make this custom form the only one available? Since this is a custom record, I have no use for the original form. Thanks!